# Compile time deduction of template member function

Tags: templates, c++11, member-functions

Is it possible to get the return type of a template member function at compile time?

I guess I need something along the lines of:

```
template<class T>
struct SomeClass
{  
     // T must have a function foo(int), but do not know the
     // return type, it could be anything
     using RType = ??? T::foo(int) ???; // Is it possible to deduce it here?
}
```

Comment: Did `decltype` not work?  I'm not sure what exactly is your problem here.  Also, is `foo` a `static` member function?  If not, you'll probably need to use `decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(1))`.  Or do you want the type of `foo` itself (eg `int(int)`)?

Comment: So, foo is not a static member function and I only want the return type of foo. e.g if foo returns int, I want int, if foo returns bool, I want that. Now, I didn't know how to make it work with decltype, is this the right thing to use because I need it at compile time? I'll try your suggestion and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved by using the [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) operator together with the [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declval) template.

`decltype(EXPRESSION)` yields – at compile time – the type that `EXPRESSION` would have.  The `EXPRESSION` itself is never evaluated.  This is much like `sizeof(EXPRESSION)` returns the size of whatever `EXPRESSION` evaluates to without ever actually evaluating it.

There is only one problem: Your `foo` is a non-`static` member function so writing `decltype(T::foo(1))` is an error.  We somehow need to obtain an *instance* of `T`.  Even if we know nothing about its constructor, we can use `std::declval` to obtain a reference to an instance of it.  This is a purely compile-time thing.  `std::declval` is actually never defined (only declared) so don't attempt to evaluate it at run-time.

Here is how it would look together.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename SomeT>
struct Something
{
  using RetT = decltype(std::declval<SomeT>().foo(1));
};
```

To see that it actually works, consider this example.

```
struct Bar
{
  float
  foo(int);
};

struct Baz
{
  void
  foo(int);
};

int
main()
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<float, Something<Bar>::RetT>::value, "");
  static_assert(std::is_same<void, Something<Baz>::RetT>::value, "");
}
```

While this does what I think you have asked for, it is not ideal in the sense that if you attempt to instantiate `Something<T>` with a `T` that doesn't *have* an appropriate `foo` member, you'll get a hard compiler error.  It would be better to move the type computation into the template arguments such that you can benefit from the [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) rule.

```
template <typename SomeT,
          typename RetT = decltype(std::declval<SomeT>().foo(1))>
struct Something
{
   // Can use RetT here ...
};
```

Comment: This is great! I wasn't exactly sure if decltype worked at compile time (it was sort of confusing, since it looked like you are calling a constructor). 
Now just one more question - suppose that foo was taking an SomeObj& instead of an int and that SomeObj doesn't have a default constructor. How would I use decltype in that situation?

Comment: In this case, you'd need to use another `std::declval<SomeObj&>()` as a parameter.

Comment: shouldn't `declval(EXPRESION)` in the second paragraph read `decltype(EXPRESION)`?

Comment: Yes, well spotted.  And thanks for correcting (alongside with my other typos), @JonathanWakely.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the argument types to your function call the following should work:

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
  typedef typename decltype(std::declval<T>.foo(std::declval<int>())) type;
};
```

If you don't you can still deduce the type of the function pointer and extract the return type:

```
template<class F>
struct return_type;

template<class C, class R, class... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)>
{ using type = R; };

template<typename T>
struct X
{
  typedef typename return_type<decltype(&T::foo)>::type type;
};
```

This will fail if `T::foo` is an overloaded function or member of `T`.

Unfortunately it is only possible to know the return type of some expression if you know with what arguments you are going to call it (which, unfortunately, often is a different place from where you need to know the return type)...